# Change boost::error_info visibility

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, visibility

I am trying to compile using -fvisibility=hidden but can not figure out how to change the visibility of a boost::error_info typedef can someone enlighten me? No matter where I put the DVEM_EXPORT in the typedef line compiler rejects it and nothing else short of editing the boost header to add the attribute there fixes the runtime problem.

```
#ifdef....
#define DVEM_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
....
class DVEM_EXPORT UnsupportedDataTypeException : public dv::BaseException<> {};
struct DVEM_EXPORT errinfo_data_type_ {};
typedef boost::error_info<errinfo_data_type_, std::string> errinfo_data_type;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typedef does not declare a type.

The type declaration carries your default - hidden - so any alias name for an instance of that type (such as `errinfo_data_type`) is also hidden.

You are right that modifying the Boost header is the most direct way. But you can also do it non-intrusively *as long as* the Boost header doesn't override visibility¹

So you can simply forward declare the same type as in `boost/exception/error_info.hpp`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7592d5e627db3c78)</kbd>**

```
#define DVEM_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))

namespace boost { 
    template <class Tag,class T> class DVEM_EXPORT error_info; 
}

#include <boost/exception/all.hpp>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace dv {
    template <typename=void>
    struct DVEM_EXPORT BaseException : virtual boost::exception, virtual std::exception {
    };
}

#include <string>
class DVEM_EXPORT UnsupportedDataTypeException : public dv::BaseException<> {};
struct DVEM_EXPORT errinfo_data_type_ {};
typedef boost::error_info<errinfo_data_type_, std::string> errinfo_data_type;

DVEM_EXPORT void foo() {
    throw UnsupportedDataTypeException() << errinfo_data_type("bar");
}
```

---

¹ which it doesn't

Comment: /Users/david/Projects/dvmon/src/common/Exceptions.h:7:50: fatal error: variable templates are a C++14 extension [-Wc++14-extensions]
  template <class Tag,class T> class DVEM_EXPORT error_info;
:(

Comment: @DavidvanLaatum what compiler is that? You can see on the live demo that C++11 compiled it fine.

Comment: Same with [GCC 4.9x](https://wandbox.org/permlink/E2hytbefpGZ9tRht) or even [GCC 4.4.x](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sXLx6NwQHJXNrT0K)

Comment: Sorry I got tripped up by crossing library boundaries ;) the top level header I put it in was in a different lib where DVEM_EXPORT wasn't defined

Comment: because DVEM_EXPORT wasn't defined it was taking that as the class name

Comment: once I put __attribute__((visibility("default"))) in directly and reordered a shitload of headers to get around predefine after define problems it works